# Integration of a vector field line using Scipy.integrate.odeint

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting the magnetic field components Bx and Bz as a function as X and Z. My main goal is to obtain the streamline which crosses the point (X,0) for any X point I give. I am using integrate.odint to plot the streamlines. The streamlines only appear for the negative values of Z and do not continue upward (see attached image).
How can I get the full magnetic field line (Z>0 and Z<0) for a given crossing of Z=0 ? Maybe I should do a backward integration as well ?
Here is the code I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

ax=plt.gca()

g10=21136
g20=1526
g30=2219
G10=-11.6

#Size of simulation box
xmax=3
xmin=0.8
NX=100
zmax=1
zmin=-zmax
NZ=100

x=np.linspace(xmin,xmax,NX)
z=np.linspace(zmin,zmax,NZ)
X, Z = np.meshgrid(x, z)
r = np.sqrt(X**2 + Z**2)


Bx=g10*3*((1/r)**3)*(Z/r)*(X/r) +(3/2)*(1/4)**4*g20*(X/r)*     (5*(Z/r)**2-1) + \
(5/2)*(1/r)**5*g30*(Z/r)*(X/r)*((7)*(Z/r)**2-3)
Bz=g10*((1/r)**3)*(3*(Z/r)**2-1)-G10+ (3/2)*(1/r)**4*g20*(Z/r)*(5*(Z/r)**2-3) +\
(3/2)*(1/r)**5*g30*((20/3)*(Z/r)**4-5*(Z/r)**2-5*(Z/r)**2*(X/r)**2+1)

Bmag=np.sqrt(Bx**2+Bz**2)

ax.quiver( X,Z,Bx/Bmag, Bz/Bmag, color='lightgrey')

plt.plot(x,z*0,c='k')

#Function that describes the vector field for the integrator
def vf(t,Y):
    X, Z = Y
    r = np.sqrt(X**2 + Z**2)
    dx=np.zeros(2)
    Bx=g10*3*((1/r)**3)*(Z/r)*(X/r) +(3/2)*(1/4)**4*g20*(X/r)*(5*(Z/r)**2-1) + \
    (5/2)*(1/r)**5*g30*(Z/r)*(X/r)*((7)*(Z/r)**2-3)
    Bz=g10*((1/r)**3)*(3*(Z/r)**2-1)-G10+ (3/2)*(1/r)**4*g20*(Z/r)*  (5*(Z/r)**2-3) +\
    (3/2)*(1/r)**5*g30*((20/3)*(Z/r)**4-5*(Z/r)**2-5*(Z/r)**2*(X/r)**2+1)
    Bmag=np.sqrt(Bx**2+Bz**2) 
    dx[0]=Bx/Bmag
    dx[1]=Bz/Bmag   
    return dx

#Integrating paths
t0=1; tEnd=360; dt=0.01;
r = ode(vf).set_integrator('vode', method='bdf',max_step=dt) #dopri5
ic=[[1,0.], [1.5,0], [2.5,0]]
color=['r','b','g']
for k in range(len(ic)):
    Y=[];T=[];S=[];
    r.set_initial_value(ic[k], t0).set_f_params()
    while r.successful() and r.t +dt < tEnd:
        r.integrate(r.t+dt)
        Y.append(r.y)

    S=np.array(np.real(Y))
    ax.plot(S[:,0],S[:,1], color = color[k], lw = 1.25)
    ax.scatter(S[-1,0],S[-1,1], color = color[k], lw = 1.25)

ax.set_ylabel("Z [Rs]")
ax.set_xlabel("X [Rs]")
ax.set_xlim(0.8,3)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)

ax.xaxis.labelpad = 15
ax.yaxis.labelpad = 15

ax.tick_params('both', length=5, width=2, which='major')
ax.tick_params('both', length=3, width=2, which='minor')

for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(2)

for item in ([ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label] +
       ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(16)
```

Here is the result I obtain:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckPaY.png